# What's the best way of getting the next-nearest neighbors in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I need to calculate something whose value is given by the following inneficient pseudo python code:

```
def foo(a,b):
   tmp = 0
   for i in graph.nodes():
       for j in graph.nodes():
          tmp += c
          if (i and j are neighbors):
              tmp += a - c
          elif (i and j are next-neighbors):
              tmp += b - c
   return tmp
```

In other words, given all the pairs of nodes, foo = a * (E = number of edges) + b * (EE = number of pairs who are not neighbors but have a common neighbor) + c * ( N(N-1)/2 - EE - E).

I tried to think on some kind of breadth first search but I couldn't.

EDIT: more info

- the graph is not static. I constantly add and remove edges, so I can't calculate this only once. I must constantly update the "list of next neighbors".
- I store the graph as an adjacency matrix.

Comment: How is the graph stored?

Comment: Is the number of vertices constant?

Comment: Yes. I keep the number of vertices constant. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a rough idea.  But first, some assumptions: 1. undirected graph 2. constant vertex-count

Your graph changes constantly.  So you need to keep the number of neighbours (edges) and second-neighbours updated efficiently.  The first is trivial, so let's look at second neighbours.

Per @Patrick's suggestion, let's work with `A^2`, and let's see how it can be efficiently updated without recomputing it from scratch every time.  `A^2_ij` is the number of length-two paths from `i` to `j`, just keep in mind that it'll have diagonal entries as well because there's always a length-two path from a vertex to itself.  If you have `A^2`, you can easily count the number of second-neighbours, so let's keep all of `A^2` updated in memory while the graph changes.

**How to update `A^2` efficiently:**

When you add/remove an edge, you change `A` by a matrix `B` that has only two entries.  Suppose we're adding (not removing) an edge.  Then `(A+B)^2  = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2`.

Assume the edge added was `(i,j)`.

- `B^2` is trivial: `(B^2)_ii = (B^2)_jj = 1`, the rest is 0.
- `AB = transpose(BA)` so we only need to compute one of the two, say `BA`.  It turns out that row `i` of `BA` is row `j` of `A` and row `j` of `BA` is row `i` of `A`, the rest is zero.  So again, it's fast to compute.

Removing edges will be similar.

You only need the *count* of second-neighbours, so instead of counting how many non-zero non-diagonal entries `A^2` has at each step, with some extra work you can count by how much the number of non-zero entries changes in `A^2` when you add `AB + BA`.

**EDIT**

This whole thing explained in a different language:

Let's keep track of the number of length-two paths between any two vertices in a matrix `M`.  When we add (remove) an edge between `i` and `j`, the number of length-two paths will increase (decrease) by one between `i` and all neighbours of `j` as well as `j` and all neighbours of `i`, so `M` is easy to update in `O(n)` time after every change to the graph.

Comment: GREAT! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. An O(N) update each time I change the graph that gives me O(1) lookup!!! Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the graph in an [Adjacency Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) `A` you can find all length 2 paths by multiplying the matrix with itself (`A^2`), if this is what you are asking.

This will take O(n^3) time to preprocess, but then you can perform lookups for neighbors and "next-neighbors" in constant time.

Comment: The problem is that my graph is not static. I'm constantly adding and deleting edges.

Comment: Please note that a node has a path of length to to *itself* as well (`1 -> 2 -> 1`), so if you use the square matrix to count next-neighbours, you need to correct for this.

Comment: "path of length *two*", I mean. Typo.

Comment: To find the number of next neighbors of vertex i, I count the number of non-zero entries on row i of A^2 and subtract one. Right?

Comment: @Rafael Yes, that should work. To make sure, I would just ignore entry `(i, i)` when counting, because if this is a directed graph without a lenght two path to itself, you may be correcting for error that is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of neighbors to your node (node_main). Visit each neighbor. Add each of its neighbors to the neighbor-of-neighbors list *unless* it is one of node_main's neighbors (or is node_main itself). Am I missing something?

Comment: My graph is an adjacency matrix. This would be O(N^2). I thought maybe there was a O(N.log(N)) way to do it. If I do this I'll visit each pair of neighbors twice, and each pair of next neighbors more than twice, I believe.

Comment: Forgive me my graph theory is about 10yrs old. It seems simple to get the list of your current neighbors and visit each one (once), as in any breadth first search. From there you are just checking if that nodes neighbors are in your neighbor list which includes the original node that you're calculating. You could also visit each neighbor and add all its neighbors to a list. Make the resulting list unique and remove the main node plus its direct neighbors, you have your list. Performance is determined by connectedness where a completely connected graph is worst case, still O(N^2), right?

Comment: But if I use an adjacency matrix, I must always check all nodes to determine the neighbor list, so getting the neighbors is always O(N), and the neighbors of the neighbors is always O(N^2), no matter the connectedness of the graph. I guess I'm stuck with O(N^2). :(